What does this elvish-looking writing mean?
In Knights of Badassdom, a character is wearing a kippah (Jewish head covering for a male) and it has some writing on it. It looks to be in some elvish-type writing. Is there any way to find out what it means? Or is it just fake to cover up whatever else was on the kippah?


This is Tengwar, one of the made up languages from LotR.

Personally I think this is off-topic here but it is probably on-topic at https://scifi.stackexchange.com.

"Is there any way to find out what it means, and if it's important for the character or the plot?" would be more interesting a question IMO than just ID'ing the language.

@Valorum it's not a language, it's a writing system

But the vowels are strangely missing, so I doubt tengwar is used here to actually write something legible.

It is Tengwar (as Valorum kindly points out).
Tengwar has two writing modes (like Arabic), the first is to write out all the vowel letters, the second is to replace the vowel letters with diacritical marks (dots and other modifying symbols) on the preceding consonant (Ómatehtar).
From the massive number of consonants in this writing, I initially thought it was Ómatehtar with the diacriticals removed (to make it less visually fancy) but in transcribing the letters, there's a vowel letter.
Additionally, to add then sense of dialects, the same lettering system was used in three different forms.
Classic   -  c  | f | n (or m) | mp | f | mb |   | ch | m (or mm) | m (or mm) | s | (unreadable)
Beleriand -  c  | f | n (or m) | v  | f | b  | o | sh | m (or mm) | m (or mm) | y | (unreadable)
General   - tsh | f | n (or m) | v  | f | b  | y | sh | m (or mm) | m (or mm) | s | (unreadable)

This leads to the following possibilities (question mark for the unknown letter)

cfnmpfmbchmms?
cfmmpfmbchmms?
cfnvfboshmmy?
cfmvfboshmmy?
tschfnvfbyshmms?
tschfmvfbyshmms?

In short, I believe that his writing is an attempt to use English letters to represent some word in a different language, a transcription of a portion of Tolkien writing now unreadable without the diacritics, or complete gibberish.
Tolkien was the first that I'm aware of to include a language system into a novel, but he was a philologist (student of the history of languages).  As part of his influence, it has been done many times since, with different degrees of effort:

The Star Wars movie, where they filmed lesser known spoken languages (South African Xhosa).
Dune heavily borrows from Arabic (relatively unknown to Western audiences at the time).
Star Trek, where Marc Okrand was hired (expert in Navajo) to develop the Klingon language to purposefully sound Alien (Navajo works very differently than English).


I used to have a copy of the Klingon Dictionary, which opened my eyes up to the wonderful world of well designed, made up languages.
